# Android : get location of object for the screen

Tags: android, dimensions

I trying to get **x,y** for any object inside the layout but I got this values when object at end corner of the screen :

**Object X : 266**

**Object Y : 361**

**Screen Width : 320**

**Screen Height: 480**

how can I know where is the object exactly for the screen? (**end,top,left,center**).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hope this helps..

```
public Rect locateView(View view) {
    Rect loc = new Rect();
    int[] location = new int[2];
    if (view == null) {
        return loc;
    }
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    loc.left = location[0];
    loc.top = location[1];
    loc.right = loc.left + view.getWidth();
    loc.bottom = loc.top + view.getHeight();
    return loc;
}
```

And I used the method this way:

```
  Rect r = TVGridUtils.locateView(activity.findViewById(R.id.imageview));                 

        float touchX=r.left+((r.right-r.left)/2);
        float touchY=(r.bottom);
```

**Note:** I had to get the middle point of the imageview which i touched

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the `width`  and `height` of the objects to `x` and `y` values

**To know where is the object exactly for the screen**

X= 0,Y= 0  **TOP LEFT**

X= screenWidth-objectWidth,Y= 0  **TOP RIGHT**

X= 0,Y=  screenHeight-objectHeight  **BOTTOM LEFT**

X= screenWidth-objectWidth,Y=  screenHeight-objectHeight  **BOTTOM RIGHT**

Answer (score 1):

```
Button b;
int x1 = b.getX();
int x2 = x1 + b.getWidth();
int y1 = b.getY();
int y2 = y1 + b.getHeight();
```